# User Authentication of Xamarin App with aspnet_Users table (SQL Server Auto Generated)

Tags: sql, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have an application which currently uses the automatically generated tables such as aspnet_Users, aspnet_Applications etc... you have probably seen them before. When you run a select query against these they are encrypted for obvious reasons, my question is this:

**Can I use the aspnet_Users table as my authentication of my xamarin app?** and if so how would I go about it? This will save me an awful lot of time creating a new user based system!

Thankyou for all advice/answers, and if it is not possible that would also be great to know :)

Comment: Yes, if you are connected to it via a WebAPI.

Comment: ok thankyou, I shall have a look into this shortly, thanks for the response

Comment: Are you looking to connect to, and authenticate against, your LightSwitch asp.net users?

Comment: Yes I am @Chris Cook, its either this or look into using Sharepoint and user access this way, as Im pretty sure there will be more information in regards to this

Comment: I'll organise some details which should point you in the right direction, though I'll need to know if you're using the Windows or Forms authentication option in LightSwitch? Also, on a totally different front, would you mind voting in favour of adding LightSwitch to the StackOverflow documentation platform (as covered in [this post on the MSDN forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d2c6f403-1580-4aaa-b228-5ab46737c2b1/lightswitch-stack-overflow-documentation?forum=lightswitch])).